# How to include equal sign in password complexity regex lookahead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, devise, regex-lookarounds

I've literally copy pasted the sample password complexity regex in https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-simple-password-complexity-requirements.

`password =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,70}$/`

I modified it to include the equal sign:

`password =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-\=]).{8,70}$/`

or

`password =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-=]).{8,70}$/`

However, when checking via irb, I encounter the following:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> 'Abcd0123' =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,70}$/
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> 'Abcd0123' =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-\=]).{8,70}$/
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> 'Abcd0123' =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-=]).{8,70}$/
=> 0
```

1. Why does the additional equal sign character incorrectly match `Abcd0123` when clearly it does not have a special character?
2. Is there a way to include the equal sign character as a special symbol?

**n.b.**

```
Mac OS X 10.14.6

checked with the following ruby versions:
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin18] - irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin18] - irb 1.2.1 (2019-12-24)
```

Comment: `*-=` means characters from `*` to `=`. Just change `*-=` to  `*=-` at the end.

Comment: Wow how did I not see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: `[*-=]` means "characters in the range from `*` to `=`", which actually means any of the following:

```
*+,./0123456789:;<=
```

To fix this, either put the `-` symbol at the *start* of the group, or the *end* of the group, or with a back-slash:

```
# Good:
[#?!@$%^&*=-]
[-#?!@$%^&*=]
[#?!@$%^&*\-=]

# Bad:
[#?!@$%^&*-=]
```

Better answer: In my opinion, this is not a good software design! Why should a password be restricted to including one of these limited, arbitrary "special characters"? Why can't I use `£` as a "special character"? Or `<`? Or `€`? Or `±`? Or `~`? ........

You could instead use a named group, to include **all** non-alphanumeric characters as "special" characters:

```
password =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=[[:^alnum:]]).{8,70}$/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for the design, I read this OWASP page about special characters https://owasp.org/www-community/password-special-characters, which is why I took the code from devise, then added the missing characters listed in the page. Though I agree that :^alnum: would be better.

Comment: There is lots of conflicting advice about password policies on the internet. I wouldn't take **anyone's** advice as gospel; and just because one group of people have defined "special characters" in a certain way, that doesn't really mean much in terms of "what's the best password policy?". (Besides, you haven't even followed their advice; your regex still doesn't include any of these characters: `" '()+,./:;<>[\]_\`{|}~` !!)

Comment: Why can't someone use a Japanese symbol as a special character? Or a rare keyboard character like `§`? Or an emoji like ? Adding extra arbitrary rules makes your system **less** secure and **less** user-friendly, so why do it?

Comment: My honest opinion about it all is that password policies like the above are designed for computers, not humans, and ideally all websites should just be [using an entropy check](https://github.com/envato/zxcvbn-ruby) instead.

Comment: Here's what I used `password =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*="'()+,.\/:;<>\[\]\\_\`{}|~-]).{8,70}$/` I didn't include everything in the sample code because the issue could be reproduced immediately with the equals (=).